# Founders of Jewish movements

Tags: history, names, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, historical-figures, heterodox

The [Baal Shem Tov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baal_Shem_Tov) was the founder of the [Hasidic Movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasidic_Judaism#Israel_ben_Eliezer), Rabbi [Israel Salanter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisroel_Salanter) was the founder of the [Musar Movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musar_movement#Early_leaders_of_the_Musar_movement), and [Theodor Herzl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodor_Herzl) was the founder of the [Zionist Movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zionism).

What are other contemporary Jewish movements, and who are their founders?  Please do not movements are not considered to be part of the [mainstream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism#Rabbinic_Judaism), such as Samaritans, Christians, Karaites, [et al.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/et_al)  Ideally, it would be nice if the answer could just become a community wiki and everybody could contribute together.  Thanks to all!

Comment: double-aa, can we retag orthodox?  Nobody would argue that they are also part of the mainstream nowadays.

Comment: Erm. "The Baal Shem Tov... Rabbi Israel Salanter... and Theodor Herzl". One of these things is not like the others. And then "Please do not [include] movements are not considered to be part of the mainstream, such as Samaritans, Christians, Karaites, et al.": so you consider secular Zionism mainstream?

Comment: @AdamMosheh But the question is not about them per se. It's about Movements. That's why I removed the tags about specific movements. If you disagree, then go ahead and retag.

Comment: @msh210 - Wikipedia has a long article on Chiloni (secular) Jewish Culture.  http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA  I suppose this would include the secular zionist movement.

Comment: @msh210 Wikipedia places [Religious Zionism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zionism#Religious_Zionism) in the page about Zionism. Even though there are some ideological differences between many religious and secular zionists, there is little in the main definition of zionism on the wikipeida page that a religious zionist wouldn't agree with. Also, just because Herzl wasn't frum, was his movement inherently anti-frum?

Comment: Rabotai, if you want, say that Herzl is the founder of Zionism in general, and that Achad Ha'Am is the founder of Cultural Zionism (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_Zionism).

Comment: @DoubleAA, fine. I've added Meretz to the list.

Comment: @msh210 OK thanks for contributing. Do you mind linking that to somewhere?

Comment: Why is "Founders of Jewish Movements" such a bad question that it is receiving these down-votes?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I assume religious scientists contribute to their fields. I also assume adjectives indicate a specific subclass related to the noun in question. Maybe that's why there is an adjective: to indicate a specific subclass related to the noun in question.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill - Wikipedia does.  See the hyperlink in the question on the word "mainstream."

Comment: Look at the chat here (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2365/).  People were talking about Reform Judaism being Judaism or not.  Monica said that according to the meta, Reform Judaism is considered "Judaism."  But practically, what does that mean?  Do we want mi.yodeya to be Orthodox only?

Comment: @AdamMosheh See discussions on meta [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/292/759) and [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/469/759).

Comment: @AdamMosheh, my downvote's reason is at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/960.

Comment: Another question: is this (http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14012/1059) to a Jewish website, i.e. the Israeli portal for Google - is it Jewish or not Jewish?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill Is the Whole World a whole thing that is also a world? Sometimes adjectives exclude and sometimes they redefine and sometimes they are part of a title: eg City Bank (is it a Bank located only in the city or only for city dwellers?). Also, how do you define religious: relating to a religion. Doesn't classical zionism have to do with Jews? Isn't Judaism a religion? So is classical zionism religious? Well, in some sense of the word the answer is trivially yes. So maybe religious zionism comes to include a different aspect of the word religious, but not to the exclusion of the first.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I hope you weren't trying to win an ideology debate by making a diyuk in English grammar!!! Even if you had made a good one it would have been _useless_ at pointing out actual differences in ideologies. These are all just arbitrary terms chosen for historical reasons.

Comment: Wait, so I'm not mainstream just cuz I'm a Reformed Hareidi Samaritan?? I take offense to that one. -1.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question is asking for a list of things that fall into the category "mainstream Jewish movement," which contains at least two very vague terms. By the way, where you say "et al.," you probably mean "[vel sim.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vel_sim.)"

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, I'm not sure where you find a consensus on J.SE regarding what fits into the category "mainstream Judaism."

Comment: @IsaacMoses Closing a question designed to only have one communal answer is kind of pointless. People can edit in new results just as before.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - I meant et al. and not vel sim., because these movements are all different.  The only tzad hashaveh shebahem is that they are all different from Orthodox Judaism, which could be considered a similarity, but only in that they are all different from something else.

Comment: @l' (Vram) - According to wikipedia, Reform Judaism and Haredi Judaism are both mainstream.

Comment: @DoubleAA - So are you saying that these are also pointless: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/959/

Comment: @AdamMosheh Not neccasarily. I'm just pointing out that closing such a question doesn't accomplish anything. Closing prevents new answers but allows edits to existing answers. Here no one would add on an answer anyway.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Great.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill - so let's close the other list questions - http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/959/

Comment: @ShmuelBrill - that is an interesting idea.  But why do meta-halakhic questions belong in the main but meta-linguistic ones belong in the meta (glossary)?

Comment: Should I change this question into "*Who are the founders of mainstream* **Orthodox** *Jewish movements?*"?  Please reply to and/or vote up this comment if you agree that it would be a good idea.

Comment: A religious zionist and a secular zionist can both be cultural zionists...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Hasidism - Baal Shem Tov
- Mussar Movement - Rabbi Israel Salanter
- Political Zionism - Theodor Herzl
- Cultural Zionism - Achad Ha'Am
- [Meretz](http://enwp.org/meretz) - Shulamit Aloni
- [Kahanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahanism) (see [chapter 10](http://www.scribd.com/doc/75639662/10/Chapter-10-Jews-and-Gentiles) of R' Kahane's book entitled Uncomfortable Questions for Comfortable Jews) - Rabbi Meir Kahane
- [Republican Jewish Coalition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republican_Jewish_Coalition) - Richard Fox
- [Centrist Orthodoxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrist_Orthodoxy) - ???
- Shemirat Torah Umitzvot - Moshe Rabbenu
- monotheism - *Hashem* (Abraham didn't invent God being alone, He just rediscovered the idea)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_movements http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_Zionism (Can somebody please delineate these into our answer?)

Comment: Everyone is invited to help contribute to this answer.